# Create an Eclipse plugin that responds to links in the internal web browser

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there any way to hook into the eclipse web browser?  I'm opening a link using IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.createBrowser, but after the page is launched I want to be able to take some action based on links clicked within the browser. Can you create a listener for browser events?

Comment: I posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031068/send-content-data-from-internal-eclipse-browser-to-a-plug-in), please check the first comment to see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.createBrowser returns an [IWebBrowser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/browser/IWebBrowser.html).  The IWebBrowser interface only defines 3 methods.

- close()
- getId()
- openURL(URL url)

I believe that openURL is used to navigate to another web page using the URL address text box.

You could write your own web browser that would allow you to create listeners for browser events.