# Send content / data from internal eclipse browser to a plug in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing both an eclipse plug in and a website. I want this two to interact with each other. The case is the following.

I have an eclipse plug in and I am using the `org.eclipse.ui.browser.IWorkbenchBrowserSupport` to open an internal browser and point it to a specific url. User can interact with my website from the eclipse internal browser without a problem.

The next thing I want to achieve is if a user clicks on a specific HTML element in my website (through the internal browser) to trigger an event or something and pass information from the internal browser to my plugin. This information can be something like : an element was clicked with properties a,b and c.

You can think it as something similar with the `mailto:` directive, when clicking that directive the mail client launches.

Any ideas on how i can achieve that? Any insights to point me to the right direction?

I have found this ([Create an Eclipse plugin that responds to links in the internal web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517680/create-an-eclipse-plugin-that-responds-to-links-in-the-internal-web-browser)) similar question which is 2 years old.

Comment: If you use the SWT `Browser` class directly you can use `BrowserFunction` to define callbacks from Javascript to your Java - see http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/

Comment: @greg-449 It seems that this can do the work. I will try it and i will update my question accordingly. Thank you!